# Why does default copy consructor not invoking when a parameter is sent by value?

Tags: c++, oop, constructor

This program initializes an object of one class and passes it as a parameter to another member function.
When I put the statement

```cpp
Address a2=a1;
```

It is showing no error. But when I take a parameter as an object

```cpp
Employee(int id, string name, Address address);
```

And call it using

```cpp
Employee e1 = Employee(101,"Nakul",a2);
```

It shows the below error.

```cpp
#include <iostream>  
using namespace std;  
class Address {  
    public:  
     string addressLine, city, state;    
     Address(string addressLine, string city, string state)    
     {    
        this->addressLine = addressLine;    
        this->city = city;    
        this->state = state;    
     }
    
};  
class Employee    
{    
     private:  
     Address address;  //Employee HAS-A Address   
     public:  
     int id;    
     string name;    
     Employee(int id, string name, Address address)    //Here it is showing an error
     {    
           this->id = id;    
           this->name = name;    
           this->address = address;    
     }    
     void display()    
     {    
           cout<<id <<" "<<name<< " "<<     
             address.addressLine<< " "<< address.city<< " "<<address.state<<endl;    
     }    
};   
int main(void) {  
    Address a1= Address("C-146, Sec-15","Noida","UP");    
    Address a2=a1; //Here it is showing no error.
    Employee e1 = Employee(101,"Nakul",a2);
            e1.display();   
   return 0;  
}
```

The error is

```sh
error: no matching function for call to ‘Address::Address()’
        {
        ^
```

Comment: You don't actually use `address` parameter to initialize `this->address` member. Assignment is not initialization. Read about constructor initializer lists in your favorite C++ textbook.

Comment: https://isocpp.org/wiki/faq/ctors#init-lists

Answer (score 5):

In the constructor of `Employee`, the member `address` isn't mentioned in member initializer list. Then it'll be default-initialzed firstly, then gets assigned as `this->address = address;` in the constructor body of `Employee`. But `Address` doesn't have default constructor.

You can initialize it in [member initializer list](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/constructor) as

```
Employee(int id, string name, Address address) : address(address)
//                                               copy-initialize (via copy constructor)
{    
    this->id = id;    
    this->name = name;    
}
```

Then `address` is copy-initialized from constructor parameter via the copy constructor.

Comment: So you are saying before invoking the copy constructor the Employee's constructor invokes Address's default constructor.

Comment: @PariRaju `this->address = address;` is assignment. So firstly `address` is default-initialized, then assigned in the constructor body by `this->address = address;`. Copy constructor doesn't kick in here. If you initialize it in member initializer list, then copy constructor is used to initialize `address` instead of default initialization.